# How can I prove that $4^{2012} \mod 8$ is $0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $4^{2012} \mod 8 = 0$

I'm not really sure what rule I should use to prove this.

Comment: $$4^{2012} = 16^{1006} = 8^{1006}2^{1006} = 8\left[8^{1005}2^{1006}\right]$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints:**

What does it mean for $x\equiv 0\mod 8$?

> It means that $x$ is a multiple of $8$

What can you say about the prime factorization of $4^{k}$ with $k\geq 2$?

Comment: I accidentally mistyped it, it is 4^2012

Comment: @Drag0 irrelevant.  Since $4^2|4^k$ with integer $k\geq 2$, the problem could have been $4^{288174873897304}$ and it would be the same proof.

Answer (score 5):

Another way $$4^{2012}=2^{4024}=2^3\cdot 2^{4021}=8\cdot 2^{4021}$$

Since $8=2^3$ you simply need to find three factors $2$ in the prime factorisation of the number.

Answer (score 1):

$4^2= 16$, then $4^{2012}\equiv (4^2)^{1006}\equiv 16^{1006}\equiv 0\ \text{mod}\, 8$

Comment: I accidentally mistyped, it was 4^2012

Answer (score 1):

Since $4^2 = 16 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$ then $$\left(4^2\right)^{1006} \equiv 0 \pmod{8}\iff 4^{2012} \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$$

An alternative proof is to realise that $4^{2012} = 16^{1006} = \left(2 \times 8\right)^{1006}$ so that $$4^{2012} = 8(8^{1005}\times 2^{1006})$$

And since $4^{2012}$ is a multiple of $8$, then $4^{2012} \equiv 0\pmod{8}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

$${ 4 }^{ 2012 }=\left( 4^{ 2 } \right) ^{ 1006 }=16^{ 1006 }=0 \pmod{8}$$